# Why this portion of PHP code doesn't work?

Tags: php

I'm trying to change color of a substring, like this:

```
$str = 'abcd<efgh>lmno';

preg_match_all('/<[\S]*?>/m', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$replacements = $needles = [];
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $needles[]      = $match;
    $replacements[] = '<span style="color:red;">' . $match . '</span>';
}

echo str_replace($needles, $replacements, $str);
```

I expect this result: `abcd<span style="color:red;"><efgh></span>lmno`
But I obtain: `abcdlmno`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue: https://3v4l.org/vArSC

Comment: Note that if you're expecting to see `<efgh>` show up in red on the page, it won't. You'll need to convert the brackets to htmlentities, or else it will be treated as an HTML tag and hide the contents.

Comment: Also just `echo preg_replace('/<[\S]*?>/m', '<span style="color:red;">$0</span>', $str);`

Comment: even if i convert brackets to htmlentities, as suggested in comment below, the substring inside < > is hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'abcd<efgh>lmno';

preg_match_all('/<[\S]*?>/m', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $str = str_replace($match, '<span style="color:red;">' . $match . '</span>', $str);
}

echo $str;
//abcd<span style="color:red;"><efgh></span>lmnoC
```